# flutter SubmenuButton Child cannot be centered

Tags: flutter, submenu

When I use SubmenuButton, setting Alignment.center for ButtonStyle doesn't work

```
runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: "菜单",
    // theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
    theme: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: Colors.blue,
      useMaterial3: true,
      // expansionTileTheme: ExpansionTileThemeData()
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("菜单工具栏")),
      body: const SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        child: SubmenuButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blue),
          ),
          menuStyle: MenuStyle(alignment: Alignment.centerRight),
          menuChildren: [
            MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu one")),
            MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu two")),
            MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu three")),
          ],
          child: Icon(Icons.star),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
```

Example:

[image]

## Why, is this a bug?

## Someone tell me why？

Answer (score 0):

We can provide the width on child by removing default padding.

```dart
body: const SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  width: 100,
  child: SubmenuButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.blue),
    ),
    menuStyle: MenuStyle(alignment: Alignment.centerRight),
    menuChildren: [
      MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu one")),
      MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu two")),
      MenuItemButton(child: Text("submenu three")),
    ],
    child: SizedBox(
      // hoped Center would solve but it is not getting enough constraints,
      // while size goes Up on flutter , I am providing width here
      width: 100 - 24, //-12*2 is padding of both side
      child: Icon(Icons.star),
    ),
  ),
```

more about [layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints).